# Can't add chars to Character ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I'm having issues understanding ArrayList in Java. I tried to declare a Character ArrayList and add a char at 0, but it returned error at list.add(0, "B") line.

```
public class ArrListTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Character> list;
    list.add(0, "B");
 }
}
```

Also I'm having issues reversing a string. Is there a way to reverse a string without using a loop?

Comment: Answer to "Also...": yes, by using recursion.

Comment: If you would use google to search for 'Java reverse string', you would find at least one concise one-liner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"B"` is instance of String, characters need to be surrounded with `'` like `'B'`.

use

```
list.add(0,'B');
```

If you want to add `B` after last element of list skip `0`

```
list.add('B');
```

Also don't forget to actually initialize your list

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To know why I used `List<Character> list` as reference type instead of `ArrayList<Character> list` read:
 [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing up [`List.set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set(int,%20E)) with [`List.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(E)). Use a character literal instead of a `String` and use

```
list.add('B');
```

after initializing the `List`

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

public class stackQuestions {

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    list.add("b");
    list.add(0, "a");// it will add to index 0
    list.add(0, "c");// it will replaces to index 0
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    ArrayList list= new ArrayList();
        list.add("B");

}
```

try this

Comment: This only works for the first character you insert. The second one will not be placed at index 0.

Comment: list.add("b");
list.set(0, "a");      by this we can replace

Comment: op has to insert **a number of characters at index 0*. You approach (add) does only work for the first character you add to the list. Afterwards they are appended to the end and not at the beginning.